# mod_rewrite .htaccess - Stylesheets mess up

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite some URL's on my website, and it works fine, I just have some issues with the stylesheets. All stylesheets works at index.php but not when url's like: localhost:8888/folder/path/(1,2,3,4)

I have my stylesheets in a file where they're listed like this:

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/site.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/viewProfile.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/viewProvider.css" type="text/css" media="screen"   title="no title" charset="utf-8">
```

Is there a way to fix this with mod_rewrite or how would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use a relative path to the style sheets. Note that the browser sends requests to

```
localhost:8888/folder/path/includes/css/...
```

in that case. If the styles always reside in that configuration at the server root, you could simply make the relative URI an absolute one. Or you remove the path portion for CSS files on the server side.

Comment: Now im just using: http://localhost:8888/folder/path etc.. :) Thanks. I guess I can do something else as long as it's not local.. :-)